# MPDF not writing html footers properly

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using mpdf to generate pdfs. So there is a problem when dealing with html footer. My Configuration is like this;

```
private $pdfMode = ''; //For loading fonts
private $pageFormat = 'A4'; //Default is A4 size
private $marginLeft = 2;
private $marginRight = 2;
private $marginTop = 2; 
private $marginBottom =2;
private $marginHeader = 9;
private $marginFooter = 9;


function __construct() {
    parent::mPDF($this->pdfMode, $this->pageFormat, '', '',$this->marginLeft,$this->marginRight, $this->marginTop, $this->marginBottom, $this->marginHeader, $this->marginFooter);
    $this->setAutoTopMargin= true;
    $this->setAutoBottomMargin = true;
    parent::SetAutoFont(AUTOFONT_ALL);
}
```

When setting AutoTopMargin is true, It is working fine even though when header is too large. But footer content is cropped and there is a so much space between body and footer

Please help in this...

Comment: try setting `marginFooter` and `marginBottom` with the same value.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But it is not working. I set same value for marginBottom and marginFooter, even though footer is not stretching as header is doing with same cofig..